# How to send mails from squirrelmail using nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, squirrelmail

Im trying to figure out a way to send emails with my squirrelmail credentials in nodmailer.

Here is my code

```
var smtpConfig = {
    service: w_server_config.service.mail.provider,
    port   : w_server_config.service.mail.port,
    secure : true,
    auth: {
            user: w_server_config.service.mail.addr,
            pass: w_server_config.service.mail.pass   
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need help with.

Comment: I want to send emails using squirrelmail credentials. In case of gmail we provide the credentials like user and password and service gmail. So how should i go about doing this with squirrelmail?

Comment: I believe you set the provider as just your domain...

Comment: ok and what about the port?

Comment: I would set the port to the port your squirrelmail is setup on. http://squirrelmail.org/wiki/index.php?page=SquirrelMailIMAPS says  IMAP over SSL uses 993 port, SMTP over SSL uses 465 port. SquirrelMail uses PHP TLS transport. It requires SSLv3 or TLS support on SSL ... So it depends on the type you're using

Comment: thanks for the help. Appreciated

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.